# Blazor - submit form without reloading (without JS)

Tags: c#, html, blazor, submit, reload

I've read many questions about how to submit form, without reloading the page. In every question the answers were, to use Ajax. In ASP.Net Applications, where i have to use JavaScript, its okay. But in Blazor i dont want to use any Java Script.

Is it possible, to use form submit, without reloading the page in Blazor?

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities
@inject NavigationManager navigationManager

    <form>
        <input @bind="ErrorCode"/>
    </form>
    @code
    {
        System.Uri uri;

        protected override void OnInitialized()
        {
            uri = navigationManager.ToAbsoluteUri(navigationManager.Uri);
            if (QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query).TryGetValue("ErrorCode", out var errorCodeValue))
            {
                ErrorCode = errorCodeValue;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should read up on EditForm a built in Blazor component.

Comment: This is the purpose of Blazor for the client to be constantly in communication with the Server.

Comment: How do i use the EditForm in Blazor like i used the html <form> ?

Comment: Do as Brian Parker suggested: read up on EditForm a built in Blazor component. Go to the docs, read and test code samples.

Comment: Alright, i will try that thanks guys.

Answer (score 0):

You will need an edit form but you shouldn't have to resort to javascript for this problem.
Add a class to your blazor app and create a communication method using either the `HttpClient` class or the `ClientWebSocket` class.
Either of these can communicate with an API or MVC endpoint the same way as any other .Net application talks to a service.